# Maintaining aspect ratio and centering at same time

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a container (main-container) with position=fixed.

I have other containers inside this container.

```
  <div class="main-container">
   <div class="container0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <iframe name="case-overlay-iframe" class="preview-iframe voice" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://cc-api-cp.adobe.io/api/v2/voice/assets/4ICee/video/embed?api_key=LucaApp1"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the iframe to keep its aspect ratio of 16:9 as people resize the window. 
I also need it to display in the center (vertically & horizontally centered)) every time. 
I also need it to keep a maximum height and width of 1280px (width) and 720 (height).

I use the CSS below to achieve this, but unfortunately, the CSS doesn't do the following:
- The Iframe is not vertically and horizontally centered.
- The iframe must keep a width of calc(100% - 440px) (see below) but its width gets smaller than that.

```
.main-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1005;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container0 {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 700px;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #262626;
}

.container {
    background: #1c1c1c;
    width: calc(100% - 440px);
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1280px;
    max-height: 720px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Can someone please help?